# "An entry with the same key already exists" appears when compiled under .NET 4

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to upgrade an ASP.NET application to .NET 4, but one page on my site contains an exception:

> Argument Exception: an entry with the same key already exists".

What is different about ASP.NET 4 that might cause this problem?

[image]

**One Solution**

Not sure why but setting `clientIDMode="Predictable"` rather than `Static` seems to have avoided this exception message.

Comment: Where does the error occur? Debug your code and show us the relevant source code.

Comment: To me it looks like the exception is thrown from Dictionary or similar collection...

Comment: if the problem still exists please post code and full stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and fixed it.

I went through my entire ASPX page and found ASP.NET control that had the same ID as another.

I also tested this fix, and found that any control that conflicts with another control on the page will cause this error.

```
<asp:Label ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<asp:Label ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

It happens when you Copy/Paste elements on the same page.

Comment: how is this possible! unless visual studio does not let it to compile and point to duplicates id. this error is freaking me out

Comment: @imanabidi when you copy/paste in VS sometimes it changes the ID, other times, it does not. You need to check to make sure each element on the page has a unique ID.

Comment: but in VS 2012 it just does not let me to do that even with copy/paste.however my problem was setting multiple Items'Selected property equal to true in DropDownList items Collection

Comment: :thank you very much. I mean I solved my problem with resetting all previously selected items with setting selectedIndex=-1 .

Answer (score 0):

This in your web.config may also cause the error by allowing duplicate IDs

```
<pages clientIDMode="Static">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too and not resolve with this

> `<pages clientIDMode="Static">`

my datagrid work fine this :

I have gridview :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" CancelText="لغو" DeleteText="حذف" EditText="ويرايش" UpdateText="بروزرساني">
                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-default" />
                            <ItemStyle Width="143px" />
                        </asp:CommandField>



                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="#" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="عنوان" SortExpression="Title" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ParentID" HeaderText="پدر" SortExpression="ParentID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Url" HeaderText="آدرس" SortExpression="Url">
                            <ItemStyle CssClass="ltr"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Icon" HeaderText="آيکون" SortExpression="Icon" />

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Order" HeaderText="اولويت" SortExpression="Order" />

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

but after add image field i see this error

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" CancelText="لغو" DeleteText="حذف" EditText="ويرايش" UpdateText="بروزرساني">
                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-default" />
                            <ItemStyle Width="143px" />
                        </asp:CommandField>


                        <asp:ImageField  ReadOnly="true"  SortExpression="Icon" DataImageUrlField="icon">
                        </asp:ImageField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="#" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="عنوان" SortExpression="Title" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ParentID" HeaderText="پدر" SortExpression="ParentID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Url" HeaderText="آدرس" SortExpression="Url">
                            <ItemStyle CssClass="ltr"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Icon" HeaderText="آيکون" SortExpression="Icon" />

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Order" HeaderText="اولويت" SortExpression="Order" />

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```